# Pagination buttons are not working fine in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

When I click pagination buttons like 2 3 or any greater it doesn't work but if click right and open with new tab it works but on same page it never works.

```
div class="page-link" style="float:left"> {!! $products->appends(Request::except('page'))->render() !!} </div>
```

Comment: <div class="page-link" style="float:left">
                            {!! $products->appends(Request::except('page'))->render() !!}
                        </div>

This is the code in my blade file

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Which URL is requested when clicking in the button? Is there an error message?